# RequireJS: How to pass updated data between modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, dependency-injection, requirejs

This is the first time I look into requirejs. I've been doing that by porting an old project of mine. So far it's coming along well. Until now.

What I've always done is keeping a site settings object containing system settings such as window height, window width, document height, scrolltop etc. In there I updated those values with resize and scroll events. Those were always global variables that I could access.

**For example (using jQuery)**

```js
var mySettingsObject = {};
mySettingsObject.Init = function() {
  this.winWidth = $(window).width();

  $(window).resize(function(e) {
    mySettingsObject.winWidth = $(window).width();
  });
};

$(document).ready(function) {
  mySettingsObject.Init();
});
```

Now I can access that variable by calling mySettingsObject.winWidth at any time from any function and it will always be up to date.

What I am trying to understand is how I can have the same behaviour using module dependency in requirejs?

**These are my two example modules**

```js
define('system', function() {
  // Window settings 
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  $(window).resize(function(e) {
    winWidth = $(window).width();
  }

  return {
    winWidth: winWidth
  };
  
});


// (is run on dom load)
define('myModule', ['system'], function(system) {
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (system.winHeight === xyz) {
      // do something
    }
  });
});
```

The system.winHeight works as expected and gives me the window height as it was on dom load. Now, if I resize the browser, how can I have that variable update itself within *myModule*, i.e. how can i make the two modules communicate.

Comment: You started your question talking about width and end talking about height. You meant to talk about width throughout, didn't you?

Comment: Yes I did :) However, width, height, in this case it's the same really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the values you want to export to an object, here called `exports`, and update the new values by updating the corresponding field on this object:

```
define('system', function() {
  // Window settings 
  var exports = {};
  exports.winWidth = $(window).width();
  $(window).resize(function(e) {
    exports.winWidth = $(window).width();
  }

  return exports;       
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that solution when I'm back behind the computer.